# AppVeyor account for GitHub organization

Tags: github, account, appveyor

I'm part of a GitHub organization developing a FOSS project. I'd like to run CI tests on Windows using AppVeyor. Currently I see my own fork of the project, and some other forks from people who have named me collaborator in GitHub. I don't see the upstream of the project, though. Apparently me being an administrator of the GitHub organization isn't enough to offer access to it in AppVeyor. But probably setting this up under my account would be the wrong approach anyway. Probably this should be under the name of the organization.

Towards that end, I'd like to have an AppVeyor account for this organization, with suitable permissions for its members. Reading http://www.appveyor.com/docs/team-setup it sounds as if AppVeyor could distinguish between users (with unique email and password) and accounts (to which projects belong), and a single user apparently can belong to multiple accounts while one account can have multiple users with different roles. In that sense, I'd like to **create a new account without creating a user for it**. Instead I as an existing user, identified by GitHub login, would like to become the first administrator of this new account, and ready to change settings and add more users. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a new account without a user. Just use some your email/password to create an account, then add existing user as collaborator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this limitation is very inconvenient. Both Travis CI and CircleCI handle the situation more gracefully by making builds for GitHub org you're part of also available under URLs on the CI side that contain the org's name.